# JPA: filter data prior to join

Tags: java, jpa

I've got a classic User <-> Membership <-> Group relation:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Membership> memberships
}

@Entity
public class Group
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<Membership> members;
}

@Entity
public class Membership
{
    @Id private Long id;
    private String status;
    @ManyToOne private User user;
    @ManyToOne private Group group;
}
```

Now I'm interested in all existing Groups and in addition want to know the Membership status of a particular user, if it exists. The results should be tuples of Group and Membership objects (or a Group object and null if no Membership exists for the particular User). In SQL that would be something like

```sql
select g.*, m.* from `group` g left join membership m on g.id = m.group_id and m.user_id = 1
```

Notice the additional restriction `and m.user_id = 1` in the join predicate which filters the data prior to join for the User who's membership status I'm interested in.

I can't seem to find a way to do this with JPA. To my knowledge, subselects in joins are not possible with JPA and something like the above can't be written directly in JPQL.

It seems I've completely gotten on the wrong track here and I would be grateful if anyone with a fresh view on this could give me a pointer.

**Update:**

It seems that [JSR 338](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) (JPA 2.1) will add support for ON conditions. Until then, how can I work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink, the ON clause is supported in EclipseLink 2.4,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON

Otherwise, you can use a native SQL query.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question as both only work outside JPA.